# Parametric: Eliminate the parameter to find a Cartesian equation of the curve.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$x = \sin \frac{1}{2}\theta$,

$y = \cos \frac{1}{2}\theta$

$-\pi < \theta < \pi$

I know I'm supposed to first solve for theta in the top equation, then plug in that into the second equation, right? Only problem is, I don't know how to solve for $\theta$ (kinda embarassing lol).

Comment: Actually, if you can manipulate the two equations so that you get the same expression containing $\theta$, you can eliminate that way.  Like $f(x) = 2\theta +5$ and $g(y) = 2\theta + 5$, so $f(x) = g(y)$.  Here it might be more handy to use $f(x) + g(y) = (\text{something involving } \theta) = \text{some constant}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1 (easy)

\begin{align*}
  x^2 &= \sin^2 \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)  \text{ and }  \\
  y^2 &= \cos^2 \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)  \text{ so }  \\
  x^2 + y^2 &= \sin^2 \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) + \cos^2 \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)  \\
      &= 1  \text{.}  &&\text{by Pythagoras}
\end{align*}  Note that the constraint on $\theta$ restrict this to $-1 < x < 1$ and $0 < y$.  (You might, as I did, briefly think the constraint boils down to $-1 < y$, but then you and I have both not accounted for the $\frac{1}{2}$.)

### Method 2 (also easy)

\begin{align*}
    x &= \sin \frac{\theta}{2}  \text{, so }  \\
    \frac{\theta}{2} &= \begin{cases} \sin^{-1}(x) + 2\pi k \text{ or}\\ \pi - \sin^{-1}(x) + 2\pi k \end{cases}, \text{ for any integer $k$}  \\
      &= \sin^{-1}(x)  \text{.}  &&\text{because } \theta/2 \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)  \\
    y &= \cos(\sin^{-1}(x))  \\
      &= \sqrt{1-x^2},
\end{align*} where the last result comes from drawing reference triangles in quadrants $I$ and $IV$ and the choice of sign of the radical is because cosine (and hence $y$) is positive on $\theta/2 \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.  We could stop here and write the result as $$
    y = \sqrt{1-x^2}, x \in (-1,1)
$$ or continue to $$
    x^2 + y^2 = 1, x \in (-1,1), y \in (0,1].
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $-1 < x < 1, y > 0, x^2+y^2 = 1$, or express $y$ as a function of $x$: $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}, x \in (-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $ \dfrac{\theta}{2} $  occurs twice, wlog let it equal $\beta.$

$$ \beta = \sin ^{-1} x $$

$$ y = \cos \beta = \sqrt { 1- \sin ^2\beta} = \sqrt { 1- x^2 }$$

or,

$$ x^2 + y^2 = 1 $$